# Java PID from cmd not changing

Tags: java, cmd

I have a swing timer that runs every 30 seconds, it calls a method where I do a search for a few specific application's PIDs that I get from a list.

This is the code in the method that is called.

```
try {
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec("tasklist");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine = "";

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        for (int i = 0; i < runningAppList.size(); i++) {
            if (inputLine.contains(runningAppList.get(i).getExecutableName())) {
                appPIDNumber = inputLine.substring(28, 35).trim();
                break;
            } else {
                appPIDNumber = "";
            }
        }
    }

    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    LoggingUtils.LogExceptions(LoggingConstants.ERROR, e.toString());
}
```

So if my app is running and I start the application I get the PID, but when I close the application it still shows the PID and does not clear it back to ""; I know I'm missing something small.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the same happen when you run `tasklist` several times on the command line? What do you get in `tasklist` when the application isn't running?

Comment: When I print the whole tasklist in my java app and I close down the application the PID is removed from the tasklist.

Comment: when running the tasklist multiple times in cmd itself it shows the PID and when I close the application the PID is removed.

Comment: Where is `runningAppList` defined and what does it contain? If I understand your code correctly it is basically checking if each `inputLine` contains the anythying present in the `runningAppLisn` and then changing the `appPIDNumber` if it finds something. If the next read input line contains anything in the `runningAppList` that pid will get assigned to `appPIDNumber`.

Comment: the runningAppList is a list I build up from a config file and contains applications exe's names. so if example test.exe exist in the tasklist I get the PID for it and assign it to appPIDNumber. But when the application closes it gets removed from the tasklist but my appPIDNumber value is still the PID from the task that was running and not reset back to "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of the `runningAppList`. If the application is closed, then that list might be empty, so the "while" loop will not be executed and the variable `appPIDNumber` will not be set to empty.

Second option is, that `r.exec("tasklist")` does not contain any line, after your application closed.

Anyway, seems you will have to set `appPIDNumber` to empty just before the "while" loop.

Comment: I read a config file and store the values in a DTO, the runningAppList is build up using these DTOs and parsed to method when its executed.

Comment: ok, just editted my answer, check if the output of "tasklist" contains any lines, after your app is closed

Comment: I checked now and the List is still populated after the application is closed, the tasklist still prints everything exluding the application after it was closed.

Comment: Adding appPIDNumber = ""; just before the while loop and removing the else resolved my issue. Thanks @papacito

Comment: If you are curious why it was not reset properly at first, run a debugger and set some breakpoints inside the while loop